# overflow-x: hidden sets overflow-y to auto/scroll behaviour

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>

#box1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 85px;
    background: blue;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
}

#box2
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -5px;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve an effect where the `#box2` is positioned partly outside of `#box1`.  I want the overflow out of the top and bottom of `#box1` to be `hidden` but the overflow left and right to be `visible`.

However when I set `overflow-y: hidden` on the container `#box1`, it seems to set `overflow-x` to scroll/auto behaviour.  I don't want any scrolling I just want the overflow to be visible.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is a [demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/7tQ9L/1/).

There are some similar question that have been asked on SO but the solutions to those questions didn't really apply to my scenario

Comment: you will need a second wrapper box, here is a nice thread: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something you cant accomplish with your HTML structure, the only way you can position a child outside a parent is to use `position:absolute` as you have, typically on a parent with `position:relative`. However, if you set the `overflow` on the parent to anything other than `auto` for either `x` or `y` it will have the effect of cropping any child elements positioned outside its boundaries, regardless of `position:absolute`

What you can do is add a wrapper, though it may not produce the solution you're after

## [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7tQ9L/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2">
        <div id="box3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 85px;
    background: blue;
}
#box2 {
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:-50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#box3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for passing on this knowledge